# Weird behaviour in asp.net/C# web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, iis

I've been trying to solve some UI issues I had on my website.

I realized that my web app was moving textboxex, dropdownlists, etc.. when after I was putting values on them.
They passed from being on the left to be on the right side of the div, weird things like that.

Well, this is the behaviour I saw when I was debugging or running from my VS2010.
Then I deployed the website and loaded into my server.
..And for my surprise, this behaviour was not happening.

Did anyone see this before?
Why is this happening?
What is the difference between debug the website, start it on the browser without debug or publish it?

Comment: You should compare the HTML source of your page while debugging and the source of it when called on production server. The problem resides in the difference between the 2 versions...

Comment: I do compare, but there are no differences. I saw it a hundred times.
It's exactly the same code

Comment: Are you debugging in IIS Express or the built-in Visual Studio development server?

Comment: if the source is 100% the same and you're using IE, I would then check in which mode IE displays your page on both environment. It could be it's running in compatibility mode on one of them, and not on the other. If not, I see no other explanation. The exact same source on the exact same browser should give the exact same result.

Comment: Are you sure all of the related javascript/css files are accessible on each machine? Check the browser console to ensure all resources are loading properyl under each scenario.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin I debug with the built in VS app server.

Comment: I have both with IE, no compatibily mode in both, I made sure I test them in same conditions.
There are no JS errors, and all CSS are loaded. I've gone over this a hundrer times, and css clases are correct, all loaded, just the behaviour is different.

Comment: Could it be because of caching? Clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: No it's not, cache is cleared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was related to style issues.
Tried with more specific styles, not letting them grow bigger than it should

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try debugging under IIS Express instead of the VS development server.  Sometimes there are subtle differences between VS Dev Server and IIS, especially when you are dealing with things like session.